# Не работает google авториазция

Tags: android

На устройстве Xiaomi mi5, не работает авторизация google, доходит до    `Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(googleApiClient);` и обрывается. Прошивка global. На другом точно таком же устройстве с этой же прошивкой работает, подскажите, что может быть

Comment: А гугл сервисы установлены?

Answer (score 0):

Помог только полный сброс настроек